# Is there a better Zwift setup I can use?

Tags: turbo-trainer

I have a road bike and a magnetic resistance turbo trainer. I use a Wahoo Blue SC to measure speed and cadence, and just put some music on whilst I ride.

I'd like to start using Zwift, but I don't know where to start. I have a laptop that has Bluetooth support, and a smartphone.

Would it be OK to connect the Wahoo SC to the laptop, and then use the smartphone for the Zwift app? Would I need to install an application onto the laptop to use Zwift?

Apologies in advance if this is off-topic.

Comment: Google 'How to get set up for Zwift' and you'll find a lot of articles including a fairly comprehensive section on the Zwift website.  Personally I wouldn't be interested in Zwift on a magnetic trainer as you don't get the interactive nature of a 'smart' trainer which in my opinion is the key part that keeps Zwift engaging.  Also as I understand it, you won't be allowed to race on a basic mag trainer either.

Comment: What Andy said, but we would need to know the model of your trainer to know if it's smart or not.